# Dictionary (same value, different key)

Tags: python, dictionary

Newbie Alert:

I'm new to Python and when I'm basically adding values to a dict, I find that when I'm printing the whole dictionary, I get the same value of something for all keys of a specific key.

Seems like a pointer issue?

Here's a snippet when using the event-based XML parser (SAX):

Basically with every end element of "row", I'm storing the element by it's key: self.Id, where self is the element.

```
def endElement(self, name):
  if name == "row":
   self.mapping[self.Id] = self
   print "Storing...: " + self.DisplayName + " at Id: " + self.Id
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll get the value `self` for every single entry in `self.mapping`, of course, since that's the only value you ever **store** there.  Did you rather mean to take a copy/snapshot of `self` or some of its attributes at that point, then have `self` change before it gets stored again...?

**Edit**: as the OP has clarified (in comments) that they do indeed need to take a copy:

```
import copy

...

    self.mapping[self.Id] = copy.copy(self)
```

or, use `copy.deepcopy(self)` if `self` has, among its attributes, dictionaries, lists etc that need to be recursively copied (that would of course include `self.mapping`, leading to rather peculiar results -- if the normal, shallow `copy.copy` is not sufficient, it's probably worth adding the special method to self's class to customize deep copying, to avoid the explosion of copies of copies of copies of ... that would normally result;-).

Comment: I'm using a sax parser, so endElement is called whenever the end of an element is reached... I'm trying to store the element at its Id

Comment: Alex, thanks, yes that's what I meant. How would I assign a "copy" instead a "reference" ?

Comment: `import copy` and store `copy.copy(self)` (or `copy.deepcopy(self)` if you need recursive copies of all containers you have as attributes: lists, dicts, etc).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're saying, then this is probably expected behaviour. When you make an assignment in Python, you're just assigning the *reference* (sort of like a pointer). When you do:

```
self.mapping[self.Id] = self
```

then future changes to `self` will be reflected in the value for that mapping you just did. Python does not "copy" objects (unless you specifically write code to do so), it only assigns references.

Comment: If you do want to copy the value, check out the copy module